# How to get Style From jQuery in angular2

Tags: jquery, css, angular, ionic2

i'm using  [farbtastic](https://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/) color picker when i button click showing color picker how to pass color code from jquery to `[style.backgroundColor]="color"`

**HTML:**

```
    <button ion-col full clear id="color-picker-handler" (click)="initiateColorPicker()">Pick Color</button>
  <ion-row class="selectedColor">
  <div class="selectedcolorCircle ion-col" [style.backgroundColor]="color" >
     </div>
     <div class="selectcolor ion-col">
     </div>
  </ion-row>
```

**TS file:**

```
    initiateColorPicker() {
      jQuery('.selectcolor').farbtastic(function(color) {
        console.log(color)});
      console.log('Clicked');
  }
```

CSS :

```
.selectedColor {
  padding: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 200px;
  text-align: center;

  .selectedcolorCircle {
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may help you,

```
import { Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  (...)
})

export class MyComponent {
  constructor(private cdr:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }


   initiateColorPicker() {
      jQuery('.selectcolor').farbtastic((color)=>{
        console.log(color)
        this.color=color;
        this.cdr.detectChanges();
      });

      console.log('Clicked');
  }
}
```

Comment: [style.backgroundColor]="color" this is correct? because color not set in background . console.log(color) showing color code

Comment: Do you want to set background color? If so, `[style.background]="color"`

Comment: Yes but background color not apply that div any other option

Comment: two error - has no exported Member 'ChangeDetectorRef'
Property "color' does not exist on type 'MyComponent'

Comment: sorry this working fine i give "ChangeDetectorRef" into from 'ionic-angular';   Thank You so much.